# Fullscreen image in background is resizing incorrectly on iOS with overflow

Tags: html, css

I am building a onepage site with mobile first functionality, but i am experiencing problems with fullscreen images on low-res screens, such as smartphones etc. I have made a rather extreme example, which obviously overflows on even big screens, but hopefully it will make sense what i am trying to do.

I would like the background to be able to extend in the height so it actually fills the screen, which is not the case. Perhaps a misuse of cover?

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width:100%;
    font-size:80px;
}

html {
        overflow-y: scroll;
}

.slider_images img {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.slider_images {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-image: none;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="slider_images">
    <img src="http://st.gdefon.com/wallpapers_original/583543_sneg_holod_portret_2560x1707_www.Gde-Fon.com.jpg" />
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5yth09vk/6/

Comment: `.slider-images` doesn't appear to have a background. Did you meant to cover the screen with the `<img>`? Because that's inline and won't be affected by the `background-` styling on `.slider-images`.

Comment: I meant to cover the screen with a image, but i see what you are saying..

Comment: Is it necessary for the `<img>` to be inline? Could you put it in the CSS as a `background-image`? Or will it be dynamic?

Comment: @LouisFéat, its a part of a slider where i fade the images in and out, therefor i prefer the `<img>` to be inline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `background-` styling from `.slider_images` as it is unnecessary.

Add `position: fixed` to the `.slider_images img` rules.

http://jsfiddle.net/louis_feat/5yth09vk/8/

UPDATE: To include an overlay over the image, include it within the `.slider_images` div which you should set as `position: fixed` with `z-index: -1`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/louis_feat/5yth09vk/12/

Comment: I have an overlay on my image with opacity. Since this is only `width:100%; height:100%`, i is not able to overflow like the cover image. If i set this overlay to fixed, i experience that it is chopping when scrolling up and down.

Comment: Is this overlay within `.slider_images`? Is it an `<img>` itself? Can you provide the markup?

Comment: I will add it to your fiddle. One moment.

Comment: `position: fixed` has very bad support in most mobile browsers.

Or at least it's a bit wonky: http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/

Comment: Auch. I better just make it static then on mobile devices.